# Watercolour shader

Tags: shaders

I am trying to achieve a watercolour effect based on a reference drawing that I've seen.

I am trying to make a shader that blends colour like watercolours blend on the paper.

I am attaching the reference drawing. The drawings are sections, but I would like to achieve similar blends between 3d objects when rendering.

**Does anyone know how to go about it?**

My initial thoughts are somehow inputting an object's colour into the colour ramp of other objects...somehow!

[image]

Comment: Have a look at [This Tutorial](https://sinestesia.co/blog/tutorials/watercolor-eevee/)

Comment: Hi Marty! Thanks for your reply. that's a really good tutorial. The main issue I want to solve is shaders on different objects blending their colours based on the view.  Although the water colour texture is spot on, the shader is doesn't take into account other objects in the scene. .